# Javascript - Generate random month

Tags: javascript, css, calendar

I am trying to generate a random month every time I refresh the browser. I have the the HTML and CSS code but cant seem to know where to start for the JavaScript. If I can be led to the right direction on how to do this I think I will be able to implement it.

```css
body {
  background: #e0e0e0;
}

#cal {
  margin: 50px auto;
  font: 13px/1.5 "Helvetica Neue", Helvetica, Arial, san-serif;
  display: table;
  box-shadow: 0px 3px 3px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.25);
  -moz-box-shadow: 0px 3px 3px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.25);
  -webkit-box-shadow: 0px 3px 3px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.25);
}

#cal .header {
  cursor: default;
  background: #cd310d;
  background: -moz-linear-gradient(top, #b32b0c, #cd310d);
  background: -webkit-gradient(linear, left top, left bottom, from(#b32b0c), to(#cd310d));
  height: 34px;
  position: relative;
  color: #fff;
  -webkit-border-top-left-radius: 5px;
  -webkit-border-top-right-radius: 5px;
  -moz-border-radius-topleft: 5px;
  -moz-border-radius-topright: 5px;
  border-top-left-radius: 5px;
  border-top-right-radius: 5px;
  font-weight: bold;
  text-shadow: 0px -1px 0 #87260c;
  text-transform: uppercase;
}

#cal .header span {
  display: inline-block;
  line-height: 34px;
}

#cal .header .hook {
  width: 9px;
  height: 28px;
  position: absolute;
  bottom: 60%;
  border-radius: 10px;
  -moz-border-radius: 10px;
  -webkit-border-radius: 10px;
  background: #ececec;
  background: -moz-linear-gradient(right top, #fff, #827e7d);
  background: -webkit-gradient(linear, right top, right bottom, from(#fff), to(#827e7d));
  box-shadow: 0px -1px 2px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.65);
  -moz-box-shadow: 0px -1px 2px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.65);
  -webkit-box-shadow: 0px -1px 2px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.65);
}

.right.hook {
  right: 15%;
}

.left.hook {
  left: 15%;
}

#cal .header .button {
  width: 24px;
  text-align: center;
  position: absolute;
}

#cal .header .button:hover {
  background: -moz-linear-gradient(top, #d94215, #bb330f);
  background: -webkit-gradient(linear, left top, left bottom, from(#d94215), to(#bb330f));
}

#cal .header .right.button {
  right: 0;
  top: 0;
  border-left: 1px solid #ae2a0c;
  border-top-right-radius: 5px;
  -moz-border-radius-topright: 5px;
  -webkit-border-top-right-radius: 5px;
}

#cal .header .left.button {
  left: 0;
  border-right: 1px solid #ae2a0c;
  border-top-left-radius: 5px;
  -moz-border-radius-topleft: 5px;
  -webkit-border-top-left-radius: 5px;
}

#cal .header .month-year {
  letter-spacing: 1px;
  width: 100%;
  text-align: center;
}

#cal table {
  background: #fff;
  border-collapse: collapse;
}

#cal td {
  color: #2d2d2d;
  width: 30px;
  height: 30px;
  line-height: 30px;
  text-align: center;
  border: 1px solid #e6e6e6;
  cursor: default;
}

#cal #day td {
  height: 26px;
  line-height: 26px;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  font-size: 90%;
  color: #9e9e9e;
}

#cal #days td:not(:last-child) {
  border-right: 1px solid #fff;
}

#cal #cal-frame td.today {
  background: #ededed;
  color: #8c8c8c8;
  box-shadow: 1px 1px 0px #fff inset;
  -moz-box-shadow: 1px 1px 0px #fff inset;
  -webkit-box-shadow: 1px 1px 0px #fff inset;
}

#cal #cal-frame td:not(.nil):hover {
  color: #fff;
  text-shadow: #6c1a07 0px -1px;
  background: #cd310d;
  background: -moz-linear-gradient(top, #b32b0c, #cd310d);
  background: -webkit-gradient(linear, left top, left bottom, from(#b32b0c), to(#cd310d));
  box-shadow: 0px 0px 0px;
  -moz-box-shadow: 0px 0px 0px;
  -webkit-box-shadow: 0px 0px 0px;
}

#cal #cal-frame td span {
  font-size: 80%;
  position: relative;
}

#cal #cal-frame td span:first-child {
  bottom: 5px;
}

#cal #cal-frame td span:last-child {
  top: 5px;
}

#cal #cal-frame table.temp {
  position: absolute;
}

#cal #cal-frame table.curr {
  float: right;
}
```

```html
<div id="cal">
  <div class="header">
    <span class="month-year" id="label"> June 2010 </span>
  </div>
  <table id="days">
    <tr>
      <td>sun</td>
      <td>mon</td>
      <td>tue</td>
      <td>wed</td>
      <td>thu</td>
      <td>fri</td>
      <td>sat</td>
    </tr>
  </table>
  <div id="cal-frame">
    <table class="curr">
      <tr>
        <td>1</td>
        <td>2</td>
        <td>3</td>
        <td>4</td>
        <td>5</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>6</td>
        <td>7</td>
        <td>8</td>
        <td>9</td>
        <td>10</td>
        <td>11</td>
        <td>12</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>13</td>
        <td>14</td>
        <td>15</td>
        <td>16</td>
        <td>17</td>
        <td>18</td>
        <td>19</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>20</td>
        <td>21</td>
        <td>22</td>
        <td>23</td>
        <td>24</td>
        <td>25</td>
        <td>26</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>27</td>
        <td>28</td>
        <td>29</td>
        <td>30</td>
        <td class="nil"></td>
        <td class="nil"></td>
        <td class="nil"></td>
      </tr>
    </table>
  </div>
</div>
```

[View on CodePen](https://codepen.io/alphaQue/pen/WOBrNV)

Comment: In your code pen is no js code, just a calender widget displaying a fixed date. Please add all relevat js code to your question.

Comment: Your question is of low quality please refer to this article: https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Answer (score 2):

This will create a random number for the month/year:

```
document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', function() {
  var randomMonth = parseInt(Math.random() * (12 - 1) + 1);
  console.log(randomMonth)

  var randomYear = parseInt(Math.random() * (2016 - 1980) + 1980);
  console.log(randomYear)
});
```

Read this article for an explanation: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Math/random

Comment: its almost what i am looking for, i am trying to change the whole calender, not the years, but just the 12 months, do you know how will i be able to implement that?